# Checking list of strings entirely contained in other list of strings

Tags: java, string, list, linked-list

I wrote this piece of code to check wheter a list of strings is entirely contained in another one and in that case delete the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<String> l1 = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> l2 = new LinkedList<String>();
    l1.add("Cc");
    l1.add("Dd");
    l2.add("Cc");
    l2.add("Dd");
    l2.add("Ee");
    LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> l = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
    l.add(l1);
    l.add(l2);
    System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + filterSublist(l));

}

static List<LinkedList<String>> filterSublist(LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> l) {
    List<LinkedList<String>> uniq = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>(l);
    l.forEach(elem -> uniq.removeIf(x -> !x.equals(elem) && elem.contains(x)));
    return uniq;
}
```

The function filterSubList should return a list of list of strings which has no lists that are totally contained in other lists.
In the example we have:

- List 1: "Cc, Dd"
- List 2: "Cc, Dd, Ee"

Since list 1 is entirely contained in list 2, the function should return a list of lists that contains only list 2.
But when I run the program I got output which is a list that contains both:

```
OUTPUT: [[Cc, Dd], [Cc, Dd, Ee]]
```

This is wrong. Is there a mistake in the filterSubList function?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `equals()` method to check for **equality** of two `lists` ?

Comment: I do not know if there is a better way. What do you suggest?

Comment: Well, you could use the `equals()` method which would return `true` if the two lists compared are equal. For Example `System.out.println(list1.equals(list2))`. But Note, that order of the contents matter. If you don't care about the order, you can use a `HashSet` @Walrider

Comment: Does the order of elements and duplicate elements matter? So do you really mean a list or a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for one list (object) containing another list (object). A new list will be alloted differently in memory whenever a new object is created, Instead check for the objects inside with containsAll:

Try this instead:

```
static List<LinkedList<String>> filterSublist(LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> l) {
List<LinkedList<String>> uniq = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>(l);
l.forEach(elem -> uniq.removeIf(x -> !x.equals(elem) && elem.containsAll(x)));
return uniq;
}
```

In case Rene's raised some points relevant to the OP, here's an implementation that pretty much follows his lead, in a different way, though.

```
static List<LinkedList<String>> filterSublistAlternate(LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> l) {
boolean[] removed = new boolean[ l.size() ]; 
outer: for(int i=0; i< l.size() ; i++)
    inner: for(int j=0; j< l.size() ; j++)
    {
        if( i != j )
        if(l.get(j).containsAll(l.get(i)))
        {
            System.out.println(i+" and "+j);
            if(l.get(i).size() == l.get(j).size())
                if(removed[i] == removed[j] && !removed[i])
                    removed[i] = true;
                else
                    continue outer;
            else
            {
                removed[i] = true;
                continue outer;
            }

        }
    }

for(int i=removed.length-1; i>=0  ; i--)
    if(removed[i])
        l.remove(i);

return l;
}
```

Comment: This solution has the issue that `uniq` may contain the same list multiple times due to the use of `equals`.

Comment: Equals is used so that the same list is not compared with itself.

Comment: Exactly because of `equals` the result may be wrong, containing duplicates. Just add another l3 = ["Cc", "Dd", "Ee"] to l and have a look at the result.

Comment: Ok, add another l4 = ["Ee" , "Dd" , "Cc" ] and then see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the solution below as it is:

- more memory efficient as it doesn't duplicate the original list
- more correct as it really checks for sublists (not just single element existence)
- more correct as it removes duplicates from the result

Code:

```
static List<LinkedList<String>> filterSublist(LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> l) {
    return l.stream()
        .filter(x -> l.stream().noneMatch(elem -> !elem.equals(x) && Collections.indexOfSubList(elem, x) != -1))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: 'More memory efficient as it doesn't duplicate the original list' - my understanding was that that was a requirement- to return a separate list. The others can be remedied easily.

Comment: @dev8080 The requirement is still met, a list is returned. But this solution doesn't copy the complete original list upfront, that's the point. So in case there are many sub-lists that are removed memory usage is lower.